# How to convert .htaccess RewriteRule for Nginx

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I'm trying to change the way pagination looks like, from: `example.com/category?page=1` to `example.com/category/page1/`

For these purpose in .htaccess I was using this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((.*)/page([0-9]+)/)$ index.php?q=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
```

But I don't understand how to do it in nginx, I tried this:

```
location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^/((.*)/page([0-9]+)/)$ /index.php?q=$2&page=$3 break;
    }
}
```

And it doesn't work, it just breaks everything (getting 404 at categories)

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

location / {

```
if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/((.*)/page([0-9]+)/)$ /index.php;

}
```

}